# Changing type of an instantiated object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Consider these classes:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int x;
}


class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public int y;
}
```

then, somewhere in the code I instantiate a new `ClassA`:

```
var o = new ClassA();
var anotherRef = o;
```

This mean I'm getting a chunk of memory with size `sizeof(ClassA)` (say 4 bytes) starting in an address like `0x100`.

Then somewhere I decide to change the type of `o` to `ClassB` and add the value of `y`.
So I want the `o` still address to `0x100` but with size of `sizeof(ClassB)` (say 8 bytes).

```
SomeMagicToChangeType(o, new ClassB());
// Now anotherRef should be a ClassB
```

In this case it will be good for anotherRef since it will reference to a correct instance.

Is it possible to do something like this in C#?

Comment: Nope, not really. You can't change the type of an object after creation. C# is a statically typed language. What are you trying to achieve? There'll most likely be a way without doing this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why are you trying to achieve such thing? When you say address `0x100` it is not fixed. GC have all rights to move it over anytime.

Comment: @Baldrick I've loaded o from database with type of `ClassA`, at some place I understand that it's real type is `ClassB` and that part is in another table. But as software did some work there are another references created. I want update the type of `o` in a way that the other references don't break.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel by the address I mean that I want the other references work fine. It's not important if the address changes. But the references must be same.

Comment: Not possible. I'll suggest you to implement a common `interface` or `abstract class` in both classes and use the interface without the concrete type.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel having `interface` or `abstract class` would be a mess since there are lots of inherited classes. The base class would have a union of all properties of all inherited types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no, you cannot do this in C#.

1. You cannot assign a `ClassB` to `o` as it is strongly typed to `ClassA`.
2. (without getting really hacky) you cannot control memory allocations or locations in C#.

If you want to do this sort of trickery, you'll need another language other than C#.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you really don't care about memory address, do you?

If so, can you just modify a class B, e.g by adding a ctor

```
B(A a) {
    this.x=a.x;
}
```

and then "convert" you A to B in a way:

```
B converted = new B(yourOldA);
```

Comment: And if you cannot modify B you can create a new class, kind of wrapper (by extending B)

Comment: The point of question is to have `converted` referenced same as `a`. Your solution is to create a new instance similar to `a`, not extending the `a`.